# SCNProgram - video input

Tags: opengl, scenekit

How can I attach a video input to a SCNProgram in SceneKit?

Without using a custom program, I could do:

```
func set(video player: AVPlayer, on node: SCNNode) {
    let size = player.currentItem!.asset.tracks(
        withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).first!.naturalSize
    let videoNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: player)
    videoNode.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
    videoNode.size = size
    let canvasScene = SKScene()
    canvasScene.size = size
    canvasScene.addChild(videoNode)

    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.diffuse.contents = canvasScene
    node.geometry?.materials = [material]
}
```

which renders the video to a `SKScene` and uses it as an input for a `SCNMaterial`.

I'd like to use a `SCNProgram` on the node, but I could not figure out to attach the player input. I don't mind if the solution doesn't uses a `SKScene` intermediate rendering. It actually sounds even better if it's possible to do without.

Comment: Why is this tagged with the OpenGL tag? Is there anything OpenGL specific to your question?

Comment: There is usually a lot of graphic things involved, like buffer binding, especially with video. I'm currently looking at this code snippet: https://github.com/asymptotik/asymptotik-rnd-scenekit-kaleidoscope/blob/01b58ed87a33c6353a398ab0bf77686e2ec96644/Atk_Rnd_VisualToys/VideoCaptureBuffer.swift#L121-L218 that uses a lot of opengl terminology. But if you think there's a more appropriate tag, lmk

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [AVPlayerLayer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayerlayer), which is a subclass of CALayer ? You can feed a CALayer to the contents property of an [SCNMaterialProperty](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty/1395372-contents).

Comment: Unfortunately, Apple doesn't think this should work that way: http://www.openradar.me/22805939

Comment: Note that in recent versions of SceneKit you can directly set an `AVPlayer` as the contents of a `SCNMaterialProperty` instance.